# How to set Foreground on selected DataGridRow (when it is not active)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, foreground

I have a style with a ControlTemplate and Triggers, something like this:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="DGR_CellsPresenter"
                                                Grid.Column="1" />
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DGR_DetailsPresenter"
                                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                                  Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <DataGridRowHeader x:Name="DGR_Header"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Magenta" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="LavenderBlush" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DGR_Header" Property="Background" Value="LavenderBlush" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

How can I set the foreground when the DataGridRow is selected, but the DataGrid is not focused. Whatever I try, it does not work!

Comment: I have found a solution! The multi trigger must also be specified in the Cell Style. Then it works exactly as it should be